# Dynamic template loading in Backbone JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, underscore.js, jst

In my current project, I am working with ROR, Backbone, Underscore JS and JQuery. In one of the view I set the JST template as follows

```
ABC.Views.BoardView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template : changeBoard,

    // el: '#boardHolder',

    events : {
        'click .count' : 'showPlaced',
        'click #newCard' : 'newCardForm',
        'click #showCardsOverview' : 'showCardsOverview'
    },
```

it continues...

Also I have a function in the bottom of the page as follows

```
changeBoard: function(){
        var params = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
        var param= params.split("=");
        var boardSize = param[1];
        //return boardSize;
        if(boardSize === 4){
            'analysis/board44'
        }else{
            'analysis/board'
        }
    }
```

Why I wrote that function is to load different JST templates for taking the parameter from the URL. But this way is not working for me. It gives me the following error

```
ReferenceError: changeBoard is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

template : changeBoard,
```

Does anyone know how to load dynamic JST template by getting the URL parameters

Thanks

Comment: try changing that to this `initialize:function(){this.template = this.changeBoard;}` and you should call like so everytime `var template = view.template();` otherwise it would land up as static non changing string

Comment: Please post the full code for `ABC.Views.BoardView` view or else a JSFiddle where i can see the problem described

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample:
template: null,

```
    events: {
    },
    initialize: function () {
        if (changeTemplate) {
            this.template = "#PublicationGroupStatTemplate";
            changeTemplate = false;
        } else {
            this.template = "#PublicationGroupReportTemplate";
        }
```

However, you can do the same in if statement in a function.. this.changeboard. Code will be something like: initialize: this.changeboard.
Hope it helps. And not too late!!

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues between Ruby and Javascript:

```
template: changeBoard,
```

The above points to a variable with name changeBoard. Later in your view you define a function called changeBoard. This is not the same thing as in Javascript a function is invoked via functionName(). I can understand this mix-up as Ruby has optional brackets whilst Javascript requires brackets when calling a function.

Also:

```
if(boardSize === 4){
  'analysis/board44'
}else{
  'analysis/board'
}
```

The above function will return undefined as no return keyword is given. Again, this is Javascript and not Ruby :)

What you want is:

```
changeBoard: function(){
  var params = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
  var param= params.split("=");
  var boardSize = param[1];
  //return boardSize;
  if(boardSize === 4){
    return 'analysis/board44';
  } else {
    return 'analysis/board';
  }
}
```

Setting a dynamic template is best done in the initialise function of your view:

```
ABC.Views.BoardView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialise: function(){
    this.template = this.changeBoard();
  }
});
```

If the boardSize is ever changing then the template should be set prior to a render:

```
ABC.Views.BoardView = Backbone.View.extend({

  render: function(){
    this.template = this.changeBoard();
    //render code continues here
  }
});
```

HTH and good luck :)